# how many threads for Rasp Pi B+ when running a script?

Tags: pi-3b+, raspbian-buster

I am tinkering around with some computer vision code....and there is an argument for the script for `the number of CPU threads to run the model.` where it defaults as 4 where I am assuming this code is for a rasp pi 4 model.

What could I use on a rasp pi 3 B+ model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You ask about "Rasp Pi B+" then "pi 3 B+".

The PiB+ has a single core; Pi3B+ has 4 (as does the Pi4).

Each core can only run a single thread at a time, although you can have as many as you like.

Whether multiple threads make the process run faster (which I assume is the objective) depends on the code. There are other reasons for multithreading.

Why don't you try and see if it makes any difference? It is not unusual for multiple threads to actually slow a process down due to the overhead.